# How to output "Summary of Stepwise Selection" table from SAS PROC REG into data set?

Tags: sas, regression, partial

I'm running in loop stepwize regression (PROC REG) for several thousand of dependent variables using about 50 independent variables.

I need to create report showing partial R-squared for every independent variable vs. each dependent variable.

It would be relatively easy task if I could output "Summary of Stepwise Selection" table from SAS PROC REG into data set.

I cannot find a way to do it.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Put `ods trace on;` before a (single) run of `proc reg`.  Then look at the log - is there any output that looks like it's that summary?

Comment: Joe's suggestion is deadon. Beside his suggestion, you can also just do a google 'ods table names proc reg' to identify the table name of your interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ODS to put that into a table.

try this:

```
ods output SelectionSummary=SelectionSummary;

proc reg data=test plots=none;
model y = a b c / selection=backward;
run;
quit;
```

This will output that table to WORK.SelectionSummary.  You can look at the PROC REG documentation in the "ODS Table Names" section to see what tables are available to output.